# Does buying armour for a bike do anything to protect your character?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

The tooltip says "Protect your car's occupants with military spec composite body panels" but I'm wondering if it does anything on a bike.

Comment: I was always under the impression that armor increased the amount of lead a vehicle could take before it finally passes away. I never knew it was supposed to protect the passengers as well...

Comment: @Nolonar Unless there's bullet proof windows, It makes sense to add armor to the car to protect the individuals inside.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. It doesn't do anything extra to protect your character.

On cars and bikes alike, the only thing the armor increases is the durability of your vehicle. The damage it can take before exploding.

Comment: So a car with windows and a hardtop won't stop more bullets from hitting occupants if the armour is upgraded?

Comment: Correct. It just increases the punishment the vehicle will take. If someone shoots you through a window, there is no additional protection.

Answer (score 2):

No. It only increases the durability of your vehicle.